# How to detect scroll position to execute jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

**Current Code (but doesn't run as it seem it would).**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1100) {
```

**Problem.**

The above looks it's supposed to work; but rather doesn't read the scroll position as you think it would, instead it fires anytime any scroll position is touched. So when the user scrolls at all it loads *(my chart.js animation)* - each time refreshing the animation after main scroll bar is adjusted the slightest.

**Requirement.**

I'm seeking to measure the height from the top or bottom of the page to ***detect scroll position*** or even using an anchor link ***> and once the specified scroll position is reached, then the animation loads, one time and stays as is at completion of animation.*** I have seen many posts on this but with no real solutions.

**Recent Update.**

I have tried both suggestions; with my *chart.js* animation script within these suggested calls but the same problem appears -- the animation refreshes and ques at every instance of touching the scroll bar.

```
var breakpoint = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400 && !breakpoint ) {
    // do stuff

    // $(window).scroll(function() {
    //   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1100) {

        // $(function () {
       //  $(document).ready(function () {

        var chart = null;

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['Home', 'Own', 'Shop', 'Buy'],
            name = 'Browser brands',
            data = [{
            //     y: 55.11,
            //     color: colors[0],
            //     drilldown: {
            //         name: 'MSIE versions',
            //         categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
            //         data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
            //         color: colors[0]
            //     }
            // }, {
                y: 21.63,
                color: colors[1],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Buy',
                    // categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                    data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                    color: colors[1]
                }
            }, {
                y: 11.94,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Shop',
                    // categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                        // 'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                    data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                    color: colors[2]
                }
            }, {
                y: 7.15,
                color: colors[3],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Own',
                    // categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                        // 'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                    data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                    color: colors[3]
                }
            }, {
                y: 2.14,
                color: colors[4],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Home',
                    // categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                    data: [0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                    color: colors[4]
                }
            }];


        // Build the data array
        var browserData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            // add browser data
            browserData.push({
                name: categories[i],
                y: data[i].y,
                color: data[i].color
            });

        }

        // Create the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Hot Links',
                data: browserData,
                innerSize: '30%'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%',
                positioner: function () {
                    return {
                        x: this.chart.series[0].center[0] - (this.label.width / 2) + 8,
                        y: this.chart.series[0].center[1] - (this.label.height / 2) + 8
                    };
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        connectorColor: 'white'
                    },
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            mouseOver: function () {

                                if (!this.connector.dynamicConnector) {
                                    var width = 16,
                                        height = 24;
                                    // Extract the connector start position
                                    var dArr = this.connector.d.split(' ');
                                    var startY = dArr.pop(),
                                        startX = dArr.pop();
                                    var start = [parseFloat(startX), parseFloat(startY)];
                                    // Construct the triangle
                                    var path = 'M ' + start[0] + ' ' + start[1] + 'L ' + (start[0] + height) + ' ' + (start[1] - (width / 2)) + ' L ' + (start[0] + height) + ' ' + (start[1] + (width / 2)) + ' L ' + start[0] + ' ' + start[1];

                                    // Convert the section angle from radian to degree and apply to the trangle
                                    // Setup rotation, x, y required by the updateTransform method
                                    this.connector.rotation = (this.angle * 180) / Math.PI;
                                    this.connector.x = startX;
                                    this.connector.y = startY;
                                    this.connector.updateTransform();

                                    this.connector.attr('stroke', this.color);
                                    this.connector.attr('fill', Highcharts.Color(this.color).brighten(0.2).get());
                                    this.connector.attr('d', path);

                                    this.connector.dynamicConnector = true;
                                }
                                this.connector.show();
                            },
                            mouseOut: function () {
                                this.connector.hide();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
//     });
// });

    }
});
```

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to do something **once** as opposed to every time there a scroll event?

Comment: One time, at the scroll location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control it with a higher scoped boolean

```
var breakpoint = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400 && !breakpoint ) {
     doStuff();
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 400 && breakpoint ) {
     doOtherStuff();
  }
})

function doStuff() {
  breakpoint = true;
  console.log('we passed the breakpoint, do stuff');
}
function doOtherStuff() {
  breakpoint = false;
  console.log('were above the breakpoint, do other stuff');
}
```

**EDIT** Added the converse functionality as well for coming back above the breakpoint.

Comment: @CaptainRon it works great, here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dahavo/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Maybe the Console works; but it doesn't run my animation code when insert and replace 'doStuff();'

Comment: Lol? So you're saying maybe my code works, but yours doesn't? Post your new code if you want help

Comment: Well my code executes, but the mission was to have it execute at the point in the page; so I wrapped your solution around my code (in the question) but it does not execute at the page position.

Comment: I can't be any more clear that the error is on your side of things and if you want help, post your code. The example in the JSbin performs exactly as you described.

Comment: I mean your implementation using my code. Set up a JSBin or fiddle?

Comment: So your code is right, but yeah; I can't get the ANIMATION to que with it at the breakpoint, here is a new question with your code and my animation code that wont execute. ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197337/chart-js-pie-animation-play-one-time-when-at-certain-position-in-page-via-vert

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove your event listener once the condition has occured:

```
var handler = function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1100) {
     // Do stuff
     $(window).off('scroll',handler);
  }
}
$(window).on('scroll',handler);
```

Comment: That works, however he may not want to lose the binding. See my answer. Can you modify yours to do the same? I like yours better as it seems cleaner