# chart.js pie animation, play one time, when at certain position in page via vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a simple pie chart, that animates on load out of the box from *chart.js* -- I am trying to allow the animation to que via a certain scroll point in a long vertical webpage -- the idea is for the below code to execute, only one time once a new users scrolls or hits page position -- the animation would que once and that's it. This is causing a lot of trouble -- as I have been able to execute and show / hide elements at page position with breakpoints and window scroll, but this animation will not execute inline with that, instead every which way I try to achieve this; what happens is the animation refreshes and replays everytime the browser scroll bar is adjusted the slightest. It just refreshes, scroll > animation refreshes > scroll > animation refreshes. Any pointers out there; the chart.js docs isn't very helpful in this since either as most of the demos are with onDomready. I have discovered ways to execute jQuery with breakpoints as you can see in the commented code below, but the actual animation within just ignores and fires at every scroll adjustment.

Also here is main external chart.js file that powers the below.

[Chart.JS](http://www.chartjs.org/) external JS

```
var breakpoint = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1300 && !breakpoint ) {
    // do stuff

    // $(window).scroll(function() {
    //   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1100) {

        // $(function () {
       //  $(document).ready(function () {

        var chart = null;

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['Shop', 'Buy', 'Own'],
            name = 'Browser brands',
            data = [{
            //     y: 55.11,
            //     color: colors[0],
            //     drilldown: {
            //         name: 'MSIE versions',
            //         categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
            //         data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
            //         color: colors[0]
            //     }
            // }, {
                y: 3,
                color: colors[8],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Buy',
                    // categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                    data: [10.20, 10.83, 11.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                    color: colors[8]
                }
            }, {
                y: 7,
                   color: colors[8],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Own',
                    // categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                        // 'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                    data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                    color: colors[8]
                }
            }, {
                y: 10,
                color: colors[8],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Own',
                    // categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                        // 'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                    data: [4.55, 5.42, 6.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                    color: colors[8],
                }
            // }, {
                // y: 2.14,
                // color: colors[8],
                // drilldown: {
                //     name: 'Home',
                //     // categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                //     data: [20.1, 0.37, 1.65],
                //     color: colors[8]
                // }
            }];


        // Build the data array
        var browserData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            // add browser data
            browserData.push({
                name: categories[i],
                y: data[i].y,
                color: data[i].color
            });

        }

        // Create the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            series: [{
                name: '',
                data: browserData,
                innerSize: '20%'
            }],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%',
                positioner: function () {
                    return {
                        x: this.chart.series[0].center[0] - (this.label.width / 2) + 8,
                        y: this.chart.series[0].center[1] - (this.label.height / 2) + 8
                    };
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        connectorColor: 'white'
                    },
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            mouseOver: function () {

                                if (!this.connector.dynamicConnector) {
                                    var width = 16,
                                        height = 24;
                                    // Extract the connector start position
                                    var dArr = this.connector.d.split(' ');
                                    var startY = dArr.pop(),
                                        startX = dArr.pop();
                                    var start = [parseFloat(startX), parseFloat(startY)];
                                    // Construct the triangle
                                    var path = 'M ' + start[0] + ' ' + start[1] + 'L ' + (start[0] + height) + ' ' + (start[1] - (width / 2)) + ' L ' + (start[0] + height) + ' ' + (start[1] + (width / 2)) + ' L ' + start[0] + ' ' + start[1];

                                    // Convert the section angle from radian to degree and apply to the trangle
                                    // Setup rotation, x, y required by the updateTransform method
                                    this.connector.rotation = (this.angle * 180) / Math.PI;
                                    this.connector.x = startX;
                                    this.connector.y = startY;
                                    this.connector.updateTransform();

                                    this.connector.attr('stroke', this.color);
                                    this.connector.attr('fill', Highcharts.Color(this.color).brighten(0.2).get());
                                    this.connector.attr('d', path);

                                    this.connector.dynamicConnector = true;
                                }
                                this.connector.show();
                            },
                            mouseOut: function () {
                                this.connector.hide();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested -- I achieved my goal with this plugin. **Appear.js**

```
<script src="http://rawgit.com/morr/jquery.appear/master/jquery.appear.js"></script>
```

__

```
/**
 * Highcharts plugin to defer initial series animation until the element has appeared. Requieres
 * jQuery.appear.
 */
(function (H) {
    function deferAnimate (proceed, init) {
        var series = this, 
            $renderTo = $(this.chart.container.parentNode);

        // Prevent pre-rendering without animation
        if (init) {
            series.group.hide();
        }

        // Prepare for animation
        if (init) {
            $renderTo.appear(); // initialize appear plugin
            proceed.call(this, init);

        // It is appeared, run animation
        } else if ($renderTo.is(':appeared')) {
            proceed.call(series);
            series.group.show();

        // It is not appeared, halt animation until appear
        } else  {
            $renderTo.on('appear', function () {
                if (!series.animated) { 
                    proceed.call(series);
                    series.group.show();
                    series.animated = true;
                }
            });
        }


    };

    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'animate', deferAnimate);
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.column.prototype, 'animate', deferAnimate);
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.pie.prototype, 'animate', deferAnimate);

}(Highcharts));
```